# Check if row was changed in a TClientDataset

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I have a TClientDataset with n fields and I have to loop through them to count how many have changed but doing:

```
if (Cds.fields1.Value <> Cds.fields1.OldValue) and (Cds.fields2.Value <> Cds.fields2.OldValue) etc....
```

or looping through Cds.fields[I] is not very 'clean'

Is there a Cds.RowChanged method or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the TClientDataSet's `UpdateStatus` property for this:

```
if Cds.UpdateStatus = usModified then
  //  current row was changed
```

Other possible values are `usUnmodified`, `usInserted` and `usDeleted`.  Unlike the `TDataSet.Modified` property, the `UpdateStatus` for the current row persists after its change(s) have been posted back to the CDS by CDS.Post.  Obviously, it's up to you which of these number values you need for your application.

As noted in the Online Help, you can use the `UpdateStatus` to set the value of a calculated field:

```
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  case TClientDataSet(DataSet).UpdateStatus of
    usUnmodified: FieldByName('Status').AsString := '';
    usModified: FieldByName('Status').AsString := 'M';
    usInserted: FieldByName('Status').AsString := 'I';
    usDeleted: FieldByName('Status').AsString := 'D';
  end;
end;
```

You can also use its `StatusFilter` property to temporarily filter a TClientDataSet to select rows with a specfic `UpdateStatus`:

```
procedure TCDSForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CDS.StatusFilter = [] then
    CDS.StatusFilter := [usModified]
  else
    CDS.StatusFilter := [];
  Caption := IntToStr(CDS.RecordCount);
end;
```

Note that `CDS.RecordCount` with the `StatusFilter` set to `usModified` does not necessarily return the same value as the `CDS.ChangeCount` property, because the `ChangeCount` value includes the number of rows **inserted** as well as the number that have been **modified**.

Comment: Note that `Cds.fields1.Value <> Cds.fields1.OldValue` will include inserted records as well. That code is from the question.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz:  I haven't tested that, but if you say so, good point.

Comment: Actually I didn't test too, I assume OldValue to be null for an inserted record.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to loop through the dataset, you can use the [ChangeCount](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.ChangeCount) property.

Comment: That gives me the overall changes, not row specific.

Comment: I was misled by your question then. *".. I have to loop through them to count how many have changed .."* led me to think your goal was to have a count.